# CSS grid layout: items overflow beyond container when using repeat with auto-fill and minmax with responsive and fixed sizes, e.g. minmax(80px, 10vh)

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid

I think I am getting a strange behavior from CSS grid layout that I didn't find a source talking about it. (this is not related to the usual misconception around the difference between `fr` and other responsive units e.g. `%`)

In my design, I need to make a grid container with responsive column filling, with width of `10vh` and with a fixed minimum width. The choice of `10vh` is for design related reasons, to make icons inside this grid scale proportionally with other items in the page.

Here is a code example: (better to reproduce directly in browser, not Jsfiddle or CodePen)

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item">11</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(80px, 10vh));
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-auto-rows: 80px;
  row-gap: 10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-style: solid solid solid solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
margin-top: 3%;
margin-left: 20%;
margin-right: 20%;
border-style: none solid none solid; /*To see borders*/
border-width: 1px;
}
```

So what I expect `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(80px, 10vh));` to do is that it will make the column widths to be `10vh`, and if `10vh` is less than `80px` it will use `80px` as the current column width. But the strange thing here is that when it starts using the minimum column width of `80px` the grid items overflow.

To investigate this more, I did the following:

Copy this code to files index.html and style.css (kept in same directory) and open index.html in browser. In element inspector in developer tools, select the `.grid-container` element and add inline style to it (usually topmost field) as: `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 10vh);`. Disable it for now.

Now you can see what's hapenning under the hood, downsize the height of the window until the grid items overflow (at which point it started using `80px`). If you toggle the added css line above on and off, you will see that the grid items order is the same in both cases. It seems that it's calculating the **number** of column 'slots' based on the `10vh` measure, but making them with widths of `80px`, so items overflow as a result. I think it should 'reflow' the items based on the `80px` measure, just as if you use `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 80px);`.

I have tried this on Firefox and Chromium, so I don't think it's a browser implementation issue.

Can anyone explain this behavior? and provide any solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: the same happen with `vw`, I would vote for a bug or a complex case of calculation

Comment: Yes the same happen with vw, and I tried that before, it just happen my design needs vh, and to keep the question simple. Where should one report such a bug?